# Comparing two norms

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

Let $x$ be a vector or $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $n_p = \|x\|_p$ and $n_q=\|x\|_q$
denotes the $p$-norm and $q$-norms of $x$. I learn (many years ago and maybe I'm wrong...) that there exists two constants $c$ and $C$ such that whatever $x$, we have $cn_p \leq n_q \leq Cn_p$.

- Is it true ?
- If it's true, how can I compute $c$ and $C$ given $p$ and $q$ ?
- What if $p=2$ and $q=\infty$ ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: draw a picture of the unit "circles" for these norms in $\Bbb{R}^2$. This will show you that the $p$-norms are all between the $1$-norm (with unit disc $D_1$: the square with vertices $(\pm 1, 0)$, $(0, \pm 1)$) and the $\infty$-norm (with unit disc $D_{\infty}$: the square with vertices $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$). If you choose the scale factors $c$ and $C$ so that $cD_{\infty} \subseteq D_1$ and $D_{\infty} \subseteq CD_1$, you will get $c n_p \le n_q \le Cn_p$ for any $p$ and $q$, including $p = 2$ and $p = \infty$. The reasoning works for any finite dimension.

Comment: Related, you can use $||x||_{\infty} \leq ||x||_p \leq n^{1/p} ||x||_{\infty}$ for all $p\geq 1$.

Comment: @Michael It's wrong. Take $x=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$, then $\|x\|_p = 1$ for all $p\geq 1$

Comment: @Serge : I do not understand your comment "It's wrong."  Here I am using $||x||_{\infty} = \max\{|x_1|, |x_2|, ..., |x_n|\}$ and $||x||_p = (\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p)^{1/p}$.  If $x=(1,0,...0)$ then $||x||_{\infty} = ||x||_p = 1$ for all $p \geq 1$. The inequality $||x||_{\infty} \leq ||x||_p \leq n^{1/p}||x||_{\infty}$ can be used to show $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty} ||x||_p = ||x||_{\infty}$.

Comment: @Michael Yes you're right and I'm (definitively) wrong. Moreover, it is even a tight bound. I was distracted. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it is true. The condition you are asking for says that these two norms are equivalent. Because all norms in $\Bbb R^n$ are equivalent, then such constants do exist. The classical proof shows that an arbitrary norm is equivalent to the maximum norm, which is $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}.$

Comment: I suppose this holds for large values of "equivalent." (+1)

Comment: @Michael: "equivalence" here means that the two norms induce the same topology.

Comment: @RobArthan : Thanks.  I also googled "equivalent norm" and found google defined it in terms of differing by at most multiplicative constants.  Your explanation is better justification about why the word "equivalent" might be used.

Comment: @RobArthan The name *equivalent norms* or (more general) *equivalent metrics* is the folklore and it is taught on any anaalysis lecture. :) So I felt to be allowed to use this name and I hoped to be understood by everybody.

Comment: @szw1710: what did I do wrong?

Comment: @RobArthan Everything OK, I wanted to point out that this is rather standard name. :-) My best regards.